# Open source implementation elastic net in C or C++

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, feature-selection, elastic-net

Can anyone provide or point me to a freely available implemention of Elastic Net in C or C++?

Comment: Added some links to libraries that I know of...

Answer (score 2):

Visit this website, there's lots of modeling implementations in C/C++ in open source including elastic net : [SPAMS](http://www.di.ens.fr/willow/SPAMS/index.html).
Have fun ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice Rcpp (C++, but packaged in an R package) version available at

https://github.com/jaredhuling/ordinis

And there is also these in C++:

1. https://github.com/mchrzanowski/improved_glmnet

Also see the associated paper,
https://stanford.edu/class/ee364b/projects/2014projects/.../chrzanowski_report.pdf

It's still work in progress though by the looks of it...

2. http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/index.html
3. http://www.mlpack.org/docs/mlpack-3.0.4/man/mlpack_lars.html
4. http://kul-forbes.github.io/libForBES/
5. http://devdoc.net/c/dlib-19.7/optimization.html#elastic_net

A pure JAVA implementation of glmnet is available here :

https://code.google.com/archive/p/lasso4j/source/default/source

And Julia implementations are available here :

https://github.com/JuliaStats/Lasso.jl

https://github.com/JuliaStats/GLMNet.jl